# MongoDB oplog stream Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a local instance of MongoDB, started with --master, and I can see in the start log that I have a replica set oplog (file: /data/db/local.1) created. And it appears local.1 is updated every time I perform and insert().

I am trying to tail / stream the oplog with the following code...

```js
MongoDB.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test',(e,db) => {
          if ( e ) { return console.log('Connect MongoDB Error',e); }
          console.log('Connected MongoDB'); 
          Server.DB = db;  
              db.collection('oplog.rs').find({}).toArray((e,d) => {
                console.log('oplog.rs');
                console.log(e);
                console.log(d);
              })  

          var updates = db.collection('oplog.rs').find({},{ 
                              tailable: true, 
                              awaitData: true, 
                              noCursorTimeout: true, 
                              oplogReplay: true, 
                              numberOfRetries: Number.MAX_VALUE 
                              }).stream();
                              
              updates.on('data',(data) => { console.log('data',data); });
              updates.on('error',(e) =>   { console.log('error',e); });
              updates.on('end',(end) =>   { console.log('end',end); });
        });
```

The Code logs the following on start...

```js
oplog.rs
null
[]
```

However there is no output from stream, I set numberOfRetries to a lower value I get the error..

```js
error { MongoError: No more documents in tailed cursor
    at Function.MongoError.create (/Users/peter/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
    at nextFunction (/Users/peter/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:637:50)
    at /Users/peter/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:588:7
    at queryCallback (/Users/peter/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:211:18)
    at Callbacks.emit (/Users/peter/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:116:3)
    at Connection.messageHandler (/Users/peter/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:282:23)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/peter/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:273:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'No more documents in tailed cursor',
  tailable: true,
  awaitData: true }
end undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

`oplog.rs` is used in [replica sets](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/). Starting mongodb with `--master` you are using long-deprecated [master-slave replication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/master-slave/), which uses `local.oplog.$main` database, so there is nothings in `oplog.rs`.

You need to start mongod with `--replSet` to benefit from replica set oplog. [Read more how to deploy and configure replica sets](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/).

Comment: I have now connected to an Atlas cluster, and still oplog.rs is empty and tail() results in the same message. (tried local.oplog.rs / oplog.rs / oplog).

Comment: Are you sure you use `local` database? How exactly you *tried local.oplog.rs*? Just to make it crystal clear, it suppose to be `MongoDB.connect('mongodb://host:port/local',(e,db)`. What do you have when you run `rs.status()` and `rs.config()` from the shell?

Comment: OK, I see now.  I would need to use db/local which would be a global db on my cluster, so I don't think it will work for my application, since I wanted to capture transaction for  a given db, not all db's.  So I can either filter the global db/local, or create new cappedCollection for each db.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You just need to filter oplog for the namespace that matches your database name

Comment: I'm multi-tenanting the Atlas instances, so wanted to avoid having a shared 'manager' process.

Comment: hmmm, I am not sure I follow. The process remains the same. You just change connection string to use 'local' database, and oplog query to get results for your database, i.e. `db.oplog.rs.find({ns:/test\./})`  for all collections in `test` database. I don't see how it makes it more 'manager' or shared in any way.

Comment: As I understand it 'local' database is 'local' for the Cluster, so if I host 'customer1' database and 'customer2' on the same Cluster then they have a common oplog in 'local' ?

Comment: local database is local to the instance, hence the name, but you are right - if customer1 have read access to oplog, he can read all writes done by other customers.